# Smart Capture submit option || Personalise Confirmation message

Tags: marketing-cloud, smart-capture

I've created a smart capture form for lead generation.
The form will be added to the website and I wanted to customize the submission message in order to add the name filled in the form.
I've tried several ampscript tests but I'm not able to get the resulat that I want !
[image]
[image]

Many thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

There may a complex programmatic approach to achieve your requirement.
However, I am sharing my point of view.

First I will cover the best/easiest solution; later ll exlain why your requirement is NOT possible to achieve out of the box.

> **Alternate Solution**: Just use the second option of 'URL Redirect' use a separate ThankYou Cloud Page as below. And make use of the [RequestParameter()](https://ampscript.guide/requestparameter/) in your ThankYou page to display any field from your form.

[image]

---

---

Below info if just in case you want to know more,
Smart Capture default JS = https://cloudpages.mc-content.com/CloudPages/lib/smartcapture-formjs.js

Basically the SmartCapture form gets submitted using AJAX method and NOT using FORM submit method; hence the page does NOT get Refreshed [instead the Payload] gets submitted asynchronously behind the scene]

Hence your thank you message, is preloaded in payload as you can see under HTML editor.
[image]

---

---

Below is the JS which calls **send()** method upon clicking Submit button.

[image]

---

---

Below is the Function making AJAX call to send data to DE and displaying confirmation message.

[image]

Comment: Many hanks Vishal for all the details :) I've used the simplest solution with request paramaeter and new page URL. It works perfectly :)

Comment: You are welcome @user126274